# Injuries caused by celebratory gunfire

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for a dataset containing injuries caused by celebratory gunfire, if possible with:

- datetime
- location
- victim's demographics
- shooter's demographics
- type of weapon

---

What I've found so far:

Ordog, Gary J., Peter Dornhoffer, Greg Ackroyd, Jonathan Wasserberger, Michael Bishop, William Shoemaker, and Subramanium Balasubramanium. "Spent bullets and their injuries: the result of firing weapons into the sky." Journal of Trauma and Acute Care Surgery 37, no. 6 (1994): 1003-1006. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7996596

> People often celebrate holidays by firing guns into the air without realizing that this can cause serious injury or death. The present study identified 118 patients treated since 1985 who were hit with spent bullets. Most (77%) were hit in the head. The mortality rate was 32%, which is significantly higher than for all gunshot wound victims in general seen at the same medical center. Laws have been enacted to help prevent people shooting into the sky, but more education and enforcement are required to prevent these serious and preventable injuries.

http://www.cdc.gov/MMWR/preview/mmwrhtml/mm5350a2.htm :

> Bullets fired into the air during celebrations fall with sufficient force to cause injury and death (1). However, few data exist regarding the epidemiology of injuries related to celebratory gunfire. In Puerto Rico, where such celebratory actions are common, news media reports have indicated that approximately two persons die and an estimated 25 more are injured each year from celebratory gunfire on New Year's Eve. The Puerto Rico Department of Health (PRDOH) invited CDC and local law enforcement agencies to assist in the investigation of injuries resulting from celebratory gunfire that occurred during December 31, 2003--January 1, 2004. This report summarizes the findings of that investigation, which determined that 1) bullets from probable celebratory gunfire caused 19 injuries, including one death and 2) such injuries affected a higher percentage of women and children aged <15 years than injuries from noncelebratory gunfire, with the majority occurring in certain public housing areas in densely populated, metropolitan San Juan. Education and enforcement of existing laws are needed to prevent these injuries.